# .css('background') || .getPropertyValue('background') return void string on Firefox Edge and iOS browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser

I'm currently stuck with a compatibility problem with jQuery / Javascript:

The following query: 
    `jQuery('.my-element').css('background');`
Works fine in Chrome and Safari (desktop), but **returns a void string** in all other browsers (FF, EDGE, and iOS Chrome and iOS Safari)

With some other css properties (e.g. `color` or `fontFamily`...) the query works fine in all browsers, using `id` instead of `class` doesn't change anything, and even with the pure javascript sintax I have the same problem.

Anyone has a strategy to overcome this incompatibility?

Comment: What specific css property are you after? Are you after the `backgroundColor` or `backgroundImage`?  Have you tried targeting them specifically rather than the aggregate property background?

Comment: I'm searching for `background url`

Comment: The url of the background would refer to the image.  Try getting `backgroundImage`

Comment: soooo good @Taplar ! :) `backgroundImage` works even on FF and iOS browsers! many thanks! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background` is sorta an aggregate for multiple css properties.  If this is returning null, you may want to target the exact property you want.  From the comments, you say you want the `background: url('...');` which relates to the `background-image` property.  So for `css()` you would lookup the `backgroundImage` property.